# Структуры си. Редкое имя

Tags: c, массивы, строки, структуры

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с кодом.

Входной файл `input.txt`: содержит список учащихся школы. В каждой строке через пробел заданы Фамилия
Имя и Отчество ученика. Требуется определить, какое имя самое редкое.
Число учеников в школе <= 10000.

Файл результата `output.txt`: содержит одну строку с искомым именем.

Пример `input.txt`:

```
Пушкин Александр Сергеевич
Луканов Александр Сергеевич
Соколова Любава Викторовна
Иванов Иван Иванович
Сидоров Иван Петрович
```

`output.txt` для данного примера: `Любава`

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    struct s_i_s
    {
        int k;
        char name;
    };
    char s_i_s;
    int t[10000];
    char s1, s2, s3;
    int i, n = 0, ans, min;
    bool fl;
    while (scanf("%s %s %s", &s1, &s2, &s3)
    {
        fl = true;
        for (i = 0; i < n && fl; i++)
        {
            if (s2 == t[i].name)
            {
                t[i].k++;
                fl = false;
            }
        }
        if (fl)
        {
            t[n].name = s2;
            t[n++].k = 1;
        }
    }
    ans = 0; min = t[0].k;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (t[i].k < min)
        {
            min = t[i].k;
            ans = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", t[ans].name);
    return 0;
}
```

Код не работает, помогите, пожалуйста, исправить

Comment: Вы всегда так код пишете? Читать удобно?

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того что вы читаете (пытаетесь читать, понятно, что получается ерунда) *строки* в *символы*:

```
char s1, s2, s3;
....
scanf("%s %s %s", &s1, &s2, &s3)
```

ну вот как какой-нибудь "Иван" может влезть в место в памяти, куда может поместиться только один символ? Вот оно и пишет куда-то в соседнюю память, портя ее и приводя к неопределенному поведению...

Это если бы было, как вы говорите - "код не работает". Но он и не компилируется - например, в строке

```
while (scanf("%s %s %s", &s1, &s2, &s3)
```

не хватает закрывающей скобки. Если даже ее добавить - `t` у вас массив целых чисел, какое там поле `name` у них?

```
int t[10000];
...
if (s2 == t[i].name)
```

Словом, садитесь-ка вы за учебники; этот код не исправлять надо, а переписывать...